# Premium Members Section of website

Tags: membership, content-restriction

Have used emember in the past and looked at Tadlock's membership as well as another premium offering by jigowatt.  However, I don't want to just hide the post's content.... I want to hide the entire post... and entire categories/taxonomies.

I'd like the menu to show "Products" and when you visit that particular page you are prompted to log in to view it.  Logging it would also "unlock"/reveal sections of the site that weren't previously visible.  For instance, the menu might now have widgets and gizmos underneath the main "products".

to me this seems different than what the plugins i mentioned before can handle.  is there a plugin that does this or am i looking at creating my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to have complete control is to use conditionals in your templates. Look at current_user_can() for specific permissions - or if its simply for being logged in you could use is_user_logged_in(). eg:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
   // echo product details
}else{
   //echo login form and message
}
```

That we you have complete control over what is displayed to whom.

Comment: kind of the "roll your own" solution i was thinking i'd need

Comment: Yeah, or you can take a mixed approach. What I've done in the past is use a plugin to manage payments and subscriptions and then use your own code to protect content. That way you can setup conditions to display different sidebars, different menus, different content etc. to logged in or guest users.

Answer (score -1):

This may help:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-content/